# Is it possible to edit a csv in colab after it has been uploaded

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to make changes to the csv file without having to do it on local and upload once again. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

When you read a csv file in google-colaboratory or other platform if you have write permission on your workspace you can save it as a csv file your edited DataFrame with Pandas.

eg:

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

# editing data frame
data_frame.drop('Column1', axis=1, inplace=True)

# after editing file yo can save it to as a csv file
data_frame.to_csv('new_sample.csv')
```